# DB2 STORED PROCEDURE : How to return appropriate error code when an insert fails?

Tags: database, db2

While writing DB2 STORED PROCEDURE ,  How to return appropriate error code when an insert fails ?
Say if i get error: Message: Data truncation during insert or another ...

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear exactly what you're needing, but if you just need to retrieve the error code while you're in the procedure, you can do so with [`GET DIAGNOSTICS`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005647.html).

If you're needing to issue your own error, you can use [`SIGNAL`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004232.html) or [`RESIGNAL`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005654.html).

(All links to the Linux/Unix/Windows Information Center... if you're on another platform, you will need to consult the proper Info Center for that platform.)